# Missing data when importing from S3 using pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Databricks to load in data from an AWS S3 Bucket.
Where I will preform analysis and write it back to another S3 Bucket. I thought my import code was working properly until I noticed some fields are coming in as null values.

I have checked the data within the bucket using AWS Athena and there are no null values. I am using the correct data types, I have checked twice.

I am looking to see if I have any unseen errors in my code?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

field = [StructField("converteddate", TimestampType(), True),\
          StructField("eventdate", TimestampType(), True),\
          StructField("year", StringType(), True),\
          StructField("month", StringType(), True),\
          StructField("day", StringType(), True),\
          StructField("userid", StringType(), True)]

schema = StructType(field)

loadName = '/mnt/master-data/year=2018/month=07/day=12/'

data = spark.read.format('parquet')\
                 .options(header='false', inferSchema='false')\
                 .schema(schema)\
                 .load(loadName)\
                 .toDF("converteddate",\
                       "eventdate",\
                       "year",\
                       "month",\
                       "day",\
                       "userid")
```

Comment: can you try loading the data without specifying the schema? You don't need to do that for parquet data anyways, and if you specify the schema incorrectly it can cause that problem.

Comment: @c.fish I only specified the schema after noticing the null values. Hoping it would help.

Comment: so i personally wouldn't trust athena over spark for the source of truth. there's nothing happening in spark that would cause null values to appear. what process is creating these files? and what are the files like inside that partition?

Comment: it looks like Athena is using the Hive parquet serde, while Spark uses it's own native serde, and Databricks has several custom enhancements to Spark's parquet serde, so it actually could be an issue with one of these serdes

Comment: you may actually need to raise a support ticket if it is indeed an issue with the parquet reader.

Comment: @c.fish the parquet files are created from external CSV files and these match the data I am seeing in Athena. So I can only assume Athena is correct. I don't know too much about the partitioning: 18.8MB, 114 parts?

Comment: are you on the latest databricks version? we recently introduced a new parquet reader and I'm worried you may have encountered a bug in it. do you have the ability to raise a support ticket?

Comment: @c.fish I am running on Databricks Runtime Version: 4.2

Comment: @c.fish I do not have the ability to raise a support ticket, we are using the pay as you go option with no support.

Comment: does it load the correct data if you use another runtime version? I would try 3.5 LTS to see if that corrects it. We recently fixed several bugs in the new parquet reader, are you still seeing this error in 4.2?